# Multiply a field with a counted field

Tags: sql, count, dbisam

I'm using DBISAM to have a table from existing datas.

My problem is :

```
NAME   |   COUNT(QTY)   |   PRICE    |    ?    | 
_______|________________|____________|_________|
  A    |       1        |    9.5     |   9.5   |
_______|________________|____________|_________|
  B    |       2        |    12.5    |   25    |
_______|________________|____________|_________|
  C    |       5        |    20      |   100   |
_______|________________|____________|_________|
```

My SQL request is `SELECT NAME, COUNT(QTY), PRICE FROM ARTICLE`.
But I can't find how to have the last column (with the ?).
I tried `PRICE * COUNT(QTY)` but DBISAM can't handle this and say "Invalid use of non-aggregated column".

Have you an idea about how I can get the last column ?

Thanks

Comment: You can just wrap this is an outer select. `SELECT col1, col2, col1 * col2 FROM (SELECT col1, col2 FROM tab1)`. I don't know DBISAM syntax specifically, but you'll likely need to alias your COUNT column.

Comment: I don't believe any database can handle such a query. Plus you can't use the ? character as it is a reserved word. Why do you want to Count the QTY field instead of Sum it?